# My Firefox extension to inject CSS wont work

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am busy developing a firefox extension. I am using the Add-on Builder

What it will do:

1. Get an ID from a PHP page (XMLHttpRequest)
2. Call another function and send that ID with it
3. That function inserts CSS with a link tag created by javascript

**My Problem:**

It won't work. If I alert the currenttheme variable, nothing happens. So the XMLHttpRequest doesn't seem to work.

My code:

**main.js:**

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var tabs = require('tabs');
exports.main = function() {
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var data = require("self").data;
scriptFiles = data.url("s.js");
pageMod.PageMod({
include: "*.facebook.com",
contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
contentScriptFile: scriptFiles
});
```

**s.js**

```
function addCSS(theTheme) {
var s = document.createElement('link');
s.type = 'text/css';
s.rel = 'stylesheet';
s.href = theTheme+'.css';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
}

function getData() {
                client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                try{
                    client.open('GET','http://localhost:8888/istyla/login/popuplogin/myaccount.php');                   
                } catch (e){
                alert( "error while opening " + e.message );
            }

            client.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (client.readyState ==4){
                        user_data = client.responseText;
                        window.user_data = user_data;
                        var currenttheme = user_data;
                        window.currenttheme = currenttheme;
                        addCSS(currenttheme);
                }
            }

            client.send(null);
}

getData();
```

P.S. The CSS file is in the data folder.

Comment: You're requesting a path that doesn't exist (perhaps it does for you, but not for every user).

Comment: It will be put on a server avalable to anyone after I have finished testing.

Comment: It seems that XMLHttpRequest is simply not defined in context of PageMod script for some reason. The same about jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content scripts run with the privileges of the page that they are in. So if the page isn't allowed to load `http://localhost/`, your content script won't be able to do it either. You don't get an immediate error due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) but the request will fail nevertheless. What you need to do is to send a message to `main.js` so that it does the request (extension code is allowed to request any URI) and sends the data back to the content script.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do that. and I am not able to find and answer. Would you be able to show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Im very new to this so not sure if I can help. Have you had a look in the error console(ctrl+shift+j) if its complaining about anything? You can console.log() and it will show in here.

Maybe use the [Request](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html) lib instead of XMLHttpRequest

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
var Request = require("request").Request;

getUserDetails : function(userID, callback)
{
   Request({
      url: Proxy.remoteUrl,
      content : {command:'getUser',UserID:userID},
      onComplete: function(response) {callback(response.json)}
   }).get();

}
```

Comment: I cant get the XMLHttpRequest to work, or the Request lib. Would you mind giving me a code example?

Answer (score 0):

As said, the content script has the same privileged of the web page where is attached, that is meaning you're under the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

You can solve the issue as suggested, so sent a message to the add-on code (that is not restricted by the SOP) and post the result back to the content script.

Here an example how the code could be: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mozilla-labs-jetpack/VwkZxd_mA7c/discussion